# How to include xamarin android ui in portable class contain view page design in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I want to add xamarin android ui design in to the portable class contain view page. Can you please suggest how can we achieve it.

Requirement :

I have create 'SamplePageView' in portable class and adding some labels in that page and create another design in xamarin android project and need to include that design under the 'SamplePageView' design. So finally I got both page design's showing in single page. In this page half part of code is implemented in portable class contain view page and another half part of code is implement using xamarin android native code.

Can you please suggest any idea for achieving this type of pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Xamarin.Forms Embedding`

This [sample on github](https://github.com/davidortinau/build2017-new-in-xamarin-forms) shows a shared Xamarin.Forms UI being embedded into non-Xamarin.Forms iOS, Android and UWP applications. With this method you can use as much or as little Xamarin.Forms in your application as desired.

You can also see this tutorial by James Montemagno explaining how to do that.

[Embedding Xamarin.Forms into a Xamarin Native App](https://montemagno.com/embedding-xamarinforms-into-a-xamarin-native-app/)